# ASP.NET Core OData update to latest version

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, microsoft.aspnetcore.odata

I am upgrading ASP.NET Core OData to latest version and struggling on the below issues:

- `DefaultODataSerializerProvider` could not be found in AspNetCore
- `SelectControllerResult` could not be found in AspNetCore
- `DynamicPropertyRoutingConvention` could not be found in AspNetCore
- `ODataPath` does not contain a definition of `odataPath.PathTemplate`
- `ODataRouteConstants` could not be found

They all belong to `Microsoft.AspNet.OData`. Can anyone please explain what the alternatives are in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData`?

Comment: [ASP.NET Core OData 8.x changelog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/changelog/aspnetcoreodata-8x) may help you.

Comment: I have already checked this but did not find any info on my particular errors

Answer (score 0):

[`DefaultODataSerializerProvider` => `ODataDeserializerProvider`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/asp-net-odata-8-0-preview-for-net-5/#dependency-injection-for-odata-services).

`odataPath.PathTemplate` : You can refer to the usage in [this code](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/blob/eb3ca8e0b02058c33212f124c810c67f453f74dc/sample/ODataRoutingSample/Controllers/ODataOpenApiController.cs#L95). Or try to use `ODataPathTemplate` directly.

For the rest I haven't found an alternative for now. I found some documentation that should help.

[ASP.NET Core OData 8.x](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData).

[Routing in ASP.NET Core OData 8.0 Preview](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/routing-in-asp-net-core-8-0-preview/).

[Current Documentation Folder](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/tree/main/docs).

[ASP.NET Core OData sample project](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/tree/main/sample/ODataRoutingSample).

Hope this can help you. If you have new discoveries, please let me know, thank you.